# How to set some static and some dynamic IPs for different computers on 1 router/modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, lan

So I currently have 3 rasberry pi's stacked up connected to my network.
My router has a built in modem (Actiontech V1000H) which has 4 LAN ports and 2 WAN ports?
Not very sure, I dont know the difference between LAN and WAN. Anyway, I would like to
setup different static IPs for each pi. Is this possible? Can I have my main IP for my normal PC dynamic then 3 static IPs? How do I go about doing this? Thanks, maybe I should learn some networking!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Pi's? Servers of some sort? You can configure your router to "reserve" LAN IP addresses for a particular MAC Address on your LAN. It will then get the same IP address every time it connects to your network. This is what should be done when running servers on a LAN and when you want to have them publicly accessible outside your WAN (via port forwarding they can be accessible over the Internet).

Comment: Ill be using one to host a few simple sites, very small game server just to mess around with and one for development purposes or just linux things. Ill have to look into that! Would be easier and save me money. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is a very standard thing to be doing, so yes it can be done, and easily. Simply read up on using your router and whatever OS you have running on your devices you want to have static IPs on.

There are two standard ways of doing this:

- Use your router to set static IPs for which ever network devices you want on static IPs to have a DHCP reservation
- set a static ip in the network config in the OS on the raspberry pi's that is outside range of IPs that the DHCP server in the router gives out, though within the subnet range of the network.